# Can a byte array be passed to an outbound file transport in mule ESB

Tags: java, mule

I have a java component that is zipping a csv file and returning an array of bytes from a ByteArrayOutputStream.  I'm attempting to pass this to a file transport to be written to the OS.  A file is written to the OS, but Windows reports that the file is invalid when I attempt to open it. First, is it possible to send a byte array to the file transport?  If so, then I think I will likely have to post another question about what I am doing wrong zipping the contents of the csv...

Here's a snippet of the java:

```
    List<String> csvFiles = (List<String>)message.getPayload();

    InputStream originalFile = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream dest = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(dest); 

    File temp = new File("users.csv");
     originalFile = new 
       ByteArrayInputStream((csvFiles.get(0)).toString().getBytes());
     ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(temp.getPath());
     out.putNextEntry(entry);
     int count;
     while((count = originalFile.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(count);
     }
     originalFile.close();
     byte[] zipFileByteArray = dest.toByteArray();
     out.close();
     dest.close();
    return zipFileByteArray;
```

Here's the relevant part of my flow:

```
 <flow name="zip-csv">
    <component class="edu.ucdavis.iet.canvas.ZipFiles" doc:name="Java"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="${message_archive.dir}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="save message to dir" outputPattern="temp.zip"/>
 </flow>
```

Comment: guess you're missing a `out.flush()` before accessing `dest.toByteArray()`.

Comment: That didn't work, unfortunately.  Thanks, though.

Comment: @geert3 @GarySharpe it's not so much an `out.flush()` than an `out.close()` before. You need to close the ZIP stream for proper checksum calculations to compute and become flush-able, on top of the buffer flushing "stuff".

Comment: Can you try writing the byte array to a file within your Java component? Just to be sure that the byte array is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the ZipTransformer class @anupambhusari submitted for this question:

> [Mule Zip File and send zipped file towards FTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37731108/mule-zip-file-and-send-zipped-file-towards-ftp-server/37742557#37742557)