# Mule ESB : java component serving zip file but unable to unzip

Tags: java, http, mule, esb, payload

The Flow gets http request and java component creates a zip file and sends back. The zip file gets downloaded but when I unzip I get error saying the 'compressed folder is invalid' . The temporary zip created by java in temp location works fine. The question is how do I set the zip file as payload?

```
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    MuleMessage message = eventContext.getMessage();

    message.setOutboundProperty("Content-type", "application/zip");
    message.setOutboundProperty("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"my_Logs.zip\"");
    File tempZip = File.createTempFile("LOGS", ".zip");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempZip);
    ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

    File logDir = new File("C:/Temp/logs");
    zipOut.setMethod(ZipOutputStream.DEFLATED);
    zipOut.setLevel(9);
    FileInputStream in =null;
    int len =0;
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    for(File file : logDir.listFiles()){
        String filename = file.getName();
        in = new FileInputStream(file);
        zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(filename));
        while ((len = in.read(buf))>0){
            zipOut.write(buf,0,len);
        }
        zipOut.closeEntry();
        in.close();
    }
    zipOut.close();
    message.setPayload(tempZip);
    return message;
}
```

Flow

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<flow name="httppayloadFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="*" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <message-filter doc:name="Filter favicon">
        <not-filter>
            <wildcard-filter pattern="/favicon.ico" caseSensitive="true"/>
        </not-filter>
    </message-filter>
    <component class="com.home.zipper.ZipLogs" doc:name="Java"/>
</flow>
```

What I am doing wrong here ? Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this which compress and serve file perfectly.

[Mule Zip File and send zipped file towards FTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37731108/mule-zip-file-and-send-zipped-file-towards-ftp-server/37736133#37736133)

Just change

In the ZipTransformer constructor, the following is deprecated.

```
registerSourceType(InputStream.class);
registerSourceType(byte[].class);
```

Use this instead:

```
registerSourceType(DataTypeFactory.create(InputStream.class));
registerSourceType(DataTypeFactory.create(byte[].class));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced following code
    message.setPayload(tempZip);
with
           message.setPayload(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(tempZip));